# AttributeError using Pandas 0.22: pandas._libs.lib has no attribute 'isscalar'

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to use pandas 0.22, due mainly to 0.23.x's problems with pd.to_sql as specified [here](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/21103), on Windows 7. When I run

```
import pandas as pd
```

I get

```
AttributeError: module 'pandas._libs.lib' has no attribute 'isscalar'
```

From

```
inference.py, line 20
```

In fact, when I upgrade pandas to 0.23.4 (the latest version at the time of writing) I get the same problem, one which didn't exist before I tried to downgrade.

If I edit pandas.cor.dtypes.inference and set `is_scalar` to be `True`, I get another error:

```
ImportError: cannot import name 'Timestamp'
```

I haven't found anywhere else online which seems to solve this.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**SOLVED**

I navigated to the pandas location in my hard drive and removed the folder manually. I imagine that my installation had been messed up and it wasn't reinstalling properly. Just deleted, and reinstalled from cmd.